# ( MVC 5 ) I loss styling when access my web application outside my PC (Only with IE)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-5

I appreciate if someone helped me with this:
I use MVC5 & EF6 & Bootstrap and every thing works great except when I try to access my application from outside my PC using IE.
I tried using Firefox & Chrome and it works as expected, but with IE (11):(
I tried with bundles and with old way , nothing work

Comment: You can use HTML5Shiv. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_browsers.asp

Comment: I think if the problem is with -IE understanding HTML5 - so it suppose to happen also when I access it locally, but it works fine locally